# how do close modal form from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
     $("#create-user").button().click(function()
     {
         $("#dialog-form").load('test.html').dialog({ modal:true, }); 
     }); 
 });
```

i have two page. from first page i want to call modal form with url test.html and i want to close the modal form from test.html page with Close

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 4):

> [SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) will automatically bind the close function (using the
>   onclick event) to any element inside the dialog with the
>   simplemodal-close class.
>
> In addition, you can programmatically close the currently opened
>   dialog by calling $.modal.close();

This means: in your closeWindow()-function, you could simply enter the line:

```
 $.modal.close();
```

Comment: Better slow down with the edits, or this will get converted to a community wiki.

Answer (score 1):

Sample.

HTML:

```
<input type="button" onclick='pop = window.open("http://www.google.com");' value="Click Me" />
<a href="#" onclick="pop.close();">Close</a>
```

Javascript:

```
   <script>
       var pop;
   </script>
```

This works. Good luck!

Comment: this my code $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#create-user").button().click(function(){ 
 $("#dialog-form").load('test.html').dialog({ modal:true, }); 
 }); 
});

Comment: @SamirDatta don't post this as a comment. Edit your question please.

Answer (score 1):

for closing the dialog you can use,

```
$("#dialog-form").dialog('close');
```

Answer (score 0):

have this code.

```
<form ... onsubmit="window.location.assign('#close')">
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#create-user").button().click(function(){ 
 $("#dialog-form").load('test.html').dialog({ modal:true, }); 
 }); 
});