# How To Close Modal Dialog from another page in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how do close modal form from another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929326/how-do-close-modal-form-from-another-page)

i have two page. from first page i want to call modal form with url test.html and i want to close the modal form from test.html page with a href="#" onclick="">Close
i am using following code to open modal dialog

```
$(document).ready(function()
 {
     $("#create-user").button().click(function()
     {`enter code here`
         $("#dialog-form").load('test.html').dialog({ modal:true, }); 
     }); 
 });
```

Comment: Could you give us an idea of markup? If you are loading only one page, `test.html`, then what you need is a visit count?

Comment: What kind of modal? Like an iframe popup kind of thing? Which library are you using?

Comment: If you are using iframe you can use : window.parent.close(). But you really need to give more information on what you are using, your sample code and what you have tried till now .

Comment: This is the second of three copies of the exactly same question. Samir you are a Spammer. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929326/how-do-close-modal-form-from-another-page and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932915/can-i-close-modal-dialog-box-from-different-page-show-in-modal

Answer (score 0):

You can close your dialog with

```
$("#dialog-form").close();
```

from anywhere in your code.

Since the dialog content is loaded dynamically, you could bind an event on the containing div

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("#create-user").button().click(function()
  {
     $("#dialog-form").on('click', '.close_link', function() {
         $("#dialog-form").close();
         return false;
     };
     $("#dialog-form").load('test.html').dialog({ modal:true, }); 
  }); 
});
```

You only need to add `close_link` to the button/link you want to use to close the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you want to close the modal from test.html , a potential solution can be to find the id of the parent which generates your dialog modal and close it This can be done this way :

```
a href="#" onclick="closeModal()"

function closeModal()
{
 window.parent.document.getElementById('dialog-form').style.display = 'none';
}
```

That will close the modal from test.html.

Comment: i want to close modal dialog also

Comment: Then close it by getting the id for the modal dialog the same way and use the same methodology to close it .